# Web Components: setter not being called

Tags: javascript, web-component

Say I have a Web Component:

```
customElements.define("custom-list", class CustomList extends HTMLElement {
  get filter() {
    console.log("get filter");
    return this.getAttribute("filter");
  }

  set filter(value) {
    console.log("set filter");
    this.setAttribute("filter", value);
  }
});
```

I wanted to use the setter method to do some initial attribute validation, but the setter never gets called. I tried setting the attribute through the HTML:

```
<custom-list filter="some value"></custom-list>
```

Only when I use JavaScript to set a property programmatically does the setter get called:

```
var list = document.querySelector("custom-list");
list.filter = "some value";

list.setAttribute("filter", "some value"); // DOESN'T WORK EITHER
```

So, it seems like setting attributes through the HTML or using `setAttribute` doesn't trigger the setter, which I partly can understand. My questions are:

- Is the setter only necessary when I want to set *properties* programmatically?
- How could I do initial validation of an attribute? In the `connectedCallback`? Say I want to only accept a certain string, how would I detect that?
- Since the property `filter` gets populated anyway, do I need the setter if I don't use JavaScript to set my attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Is the setter only necessary when I want to set properties programmatically?

Yes, at least if you want/need to run some tests/filtering upon the value you want to set.

- How could I do initial validation of an attribute? In the connectedCallback? Say I want to only accept a certain string, how would I detect that?

Yep, connectedCallback or even in the constructor.

- Since the property filter gets populated anyway, do I need the setter if I don't use JavaScript to set my attributes ?

No, you don't

This being said if you need a clear control over your custom attributes, i would suggest creating an internal state that you populate once when your custom element is being created and then when attributeChangedCallback is being called. That would give you some advantages :

- you get control over the values that value your custom attributes.
- you get an internal state that you can use to re-render your component if you need to

Here is an example :

```
customElements.define("custom-list", class CustomList extends HTMLElement {

    static get observedAttributes() { return ['filter']; }

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            filter: null
        };
        this.setFilter(this.getAttribute("filter"));
    }

    attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
        if (name === "filter") {
            this.setFilter(newValue);
        }
    }

    getFilter() {
        console.log("get filter");
        return this.state.filter;
    }

    setFilter(value) {
        // You can add some logic here to control the value
        console.log("set filter");
        this.state.filter=value;
    }
});
```

Then you can call the following to change your internal state :

```
list.setAttribute("filter", "some value");
```

Would be interrested to get some feedback on this from the community. Anyway, hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clear and detailed explanation, helped me a lot to understand what's going on!

Answer (score 3):

getters and setters are a way to define **properties** that allow your code to receive and return values other than strings.

Attributes on the element are always string values. You can emulate a non-string in an attribute by parsing the value. But they are always set in as strings and read back as strings.

If you want to have code run when an attribute is changed then you need to add the `attributeChangedCallback` function and indicate which attributes you are watching in the `observedAttributes` static getter.

Attributes can be set in JavaScript by calling `setAttribute` and `removeAttribute`. They are also set when the browser parses your HTML due to a page load or setting `innerHTML`. But even then the browser does not set these until after the constructor is called when the browser, eventually, calls `setAttribute` in the background.

```js
customElements.define("custom-list", class CustomList extends HTMLElement {
  static get observedAttributes() { return ['filter']; }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this._filter = null; // Save the initial value
  }

  attributeChangedCallback(attr, oldVal, newVal) {
    if (oldVal != newVal) {
      // Only set this value if it is different
      this.filter = newVal; // Call the setter
    }
  }

  get filter() {
    console.log("get filter");
    return this._filter; // Return the internal value
  }

  set filter(value) {
    // Only run this if the new value is different from the internal value
    if (value !== this._filter) {
      console.log(`set filter ${value}`);
      this._filter = value; // Set the internal value
      this.textContent = value;
      // If you want the filter property to always show
      // in the attributes then do this:
      if (value !== null) {
        this.setAttribute('filter', value);
      } else {
        this.removeAttribute('filter');
      }
    }
  }
});

const el = document.querySelector('custom-list');
setTimeout(() => {
  el.filter = 'happy';
}, 2000);
```

```html
<custom-list filter="10"></custom-list>
```

**Always** check to see if your `oldVal` and `newVal` are different in the function `attributeChangedCallback`. Otherwise you could end up in an endless loop.

It is also recommended that you check for different values in your setters. *Again, to avoid getting into an endless loop.*

Setters also allow you to take specific data types. For example you could check to see if the value for `value` was a number and, if not, throw a `TypeError`. Or you just convert the incoming value to the correct type.

Setters also allow you to make sure a value is valid. Maybe it must be a positive number or one of three possible strings. If it isn't you can throw a `RangeError`.

But you have to remember that attributes are always strings and properties can be anything.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it's a nice addition to what Samuel wrote in his reply.

Comment: Why use an underscore in this._filter ???

Comment: I wrote this before private properties were available and it was common to use underscore to indicate a property that should not be accessed as public. I now always use private properties.